# Priming spackling in preparation for repainting room

Tags: drywall, painting, repainting, primer, patching-drywall

We are painting a room that was previously painted, however there 2 areas approx. 5"x2' that required some re-tapping and spackling to fix cracks in the drywall.

The already painted non-fixed areas as I understand do not require a coat of primer, however I figured that all the newly fixed areas will require a coat of primer. Will priming one area, but not priming the entire room (as 98% of the room doesn't require it) affect the final paint-job?

Current paint: yellowish-orange
primer: white (obviously)
new paint color: beige

Answer (score 1):

Priming those small areas could be a factor, but not likely the sole or primary causal factor of an undesired issue with the final surface treatment appearance. The difference in the *surface texture* at the repair sites will be your nemesis.

The way the light reflects from the surface (look up *hold-out factor*) will change the way the repair areas look compared to the previously painted areas. In critical applications, professional decorators would skim coat the *entire wall* with plaster to avoid this issue. All is not lost, however. Flat and low-sheen paints are much more forgiving than glossy paints. Walls where the light strikes perpendicular rather than at an angle makes imperfections hard to see. Use of a paint roller with a bit of nap will really help hide surface imperfections.

And there is always texture. You could use a plaster-base texture material to completely hide the repair, or use a textured paint additive.

In the end, if this is a normal home with normal people looking at it (as opposed to a museum, showroom, executive suite, etc.) you will probably be the only one who sees it.